# how to upload a file in dynamic paths using java

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

```
String rootPath = "C:\\Users\\khaja\\workspace\\ServletFileUploadDownloadExample";
ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
String relativePath = ctx.getInitParameter("tempfile.dir");
File file = new File(rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
if(!file.exists()) file.mkdirs();
System.out.println("File Directory created to be used for storing files");
ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR_FILE", file);
ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR", rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
```

I want to upload the files using java or jsp or servlets. 
Whenever I upload a file it should ask the path dynamically by a pop up window asking where to store.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some references:

- Uploading file using JSP and servlet https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/file-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp.html
- Popup input before submission and append input to form (using jquery & bootstrap) https://jsfiddle.net/u3sr6smr/:

```js
$('#submit-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#my-modal').modal('show')
})

$('#upload-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var fileLocation = $('#file-location').val(),
        inputExist = $('input[name=fileLocation]', '#upload-form').length > 0
    if (fileLocation && !inputExist) {
        var fileLocationInput = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'fileLocation').attr('value', fileLocation)
        $('#upload-form').append(fileLocationInput).submit()
    }
})
```